# print invoice using thermal esc/pos using android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pos, escpos

[image]

This receipt print using .net using drawing class.
it is in arial font .esc/pos not support arial font .
how can achieive like this using android .i am naive in this.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the whole receipt as one monochrome image, and render it with the font you want, the design and layout you want, and create the data.

If you print it using the ESC/POS image data printing function, you will get the desired result.

Comment: i created receipt using this.https://github.com/imrankst1221/Thermal-Printer-in-Android.but i coudnt fullfill like this.Can you provide any example.anyway thank you for your great information

Comment: The functions of the ESC/POS command transmission library are used only for printing the resulting image. The important thing is the process of creating the receipt image data, which is not related to the printer library.